# Mapping same table twice in different associations in MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, mybatis

I have 6 tables structured like this (there is a more descriptive example at the bottom):

**A**

Every item is related to one item in B and one item in C.

```
aid | bid | cid
```

**B**

Every item is related to multiple items in D.

```
bid
```

**C**

Every item is related to multiple items in D.

```
cid
```

**D**

Every item is related to multiple items in B and C.

```
did
```

**E**

Maps items in B to items in D.

```
bid | did
```

**F**

Maps items in C to items in D.

```
cid | did
```

Now I'm trying to write a mapper in MyBatis that maps the items in table A. The mapper has an association to the mappers of table B and C, and the mappers of tables B and C both have a collection containing items of table D.

Individually mapping either B or C to items of table D isn't a problem, since then a simple join operation using either E or F is enough.
However, the problem arises when trying to map everything from the perspective of table A.
As table A is associated to both table B and C, and they are both associated with table D, I don't know how to let the mappers of B and C distinguish between the items in table D that are meant for them.

Basically, I'm trying to join D to B and C from the perspective of A's mapper.

Is there a way to join table D twice in MyBatis, whilst keeping a distinction between the two joins so the mappers of B and C can distinguish between the two?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

Here's a small example with more descriptive names.

**houses**

```
houseid | livingroomid | kitchenid
1       | 1            | 1
```

**livingrooms**

```
livingroomid
1
```

**kitchens**

```
kitchenid
1
```

**furniture**

```
furnitureid | furniturename
1           | couch
2           | lamp
3           | fridge
```

**livingroomfurniture**

```
livingroomid | furnitureid
1            | 1
1            | 2
```

**kitchenfurniture**

```
kitchenid | furnitureid
1         | 2
1         | 3
```

My mappers currently:

**Mapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper>
    <resultMap type="com.project.models.house.House" id="HouseResult">
        <id             property="id"           column="houseid" />
        <association    property="livingroom"   resultMap="LivingRoomResult" />
        <association    property="kitchen"      resultMap="KitchenResult" />
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap type="com.project.models.livingroom.LivingRoom" id="LivingRoomResult">
        <id             property="id"           column="livingroomid" />
        <collection     property="furniture"    resultMap="FurnitureResult" />
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap type="com.project.models.kitchen.Kitchen" id="KitchenResult">
        <id             property="id"           column="kitchenid" />
        <collection     property="furniture"    resultMap="FurnitureResult" />
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap type="com.project.models.furniture.Furniture" id="FurnitureResult">
        <id             property="id"           column="furnitureid" />
        <result         property="name"         column="furniturename" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getAllHouses" resultMap="HouseResult">
        SELECT
          houses.houseid,
          houses.livingroomid,
          houses.kitchenid

        FROM houses

        -- Get the living room
        INNER JOIN livingrooms ON livingrooms.livingroomid = houses.livingroomid

        -- Get the kitchen
        INNER JOIN kitchens ON kitchens.kitchenid = kitchens.kitchenid

        -- Here somehow join the furniture for both the living room and the kitchen?
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Comment: for me hard to imagine in abstraction, without real code

Comment: @JacekCz I tried to abstract as much as possible as the code is quite long and complicated, but I could try to write a small sample

Comment: @JacekCz I added an example to my original post.

Comment: `... is there a way to join table D twice ...` Yes: just join it twice, with two different table aliases. `... in MyBatis, ...` Dont know. It *should* be possible.

Comment: @joop Yes as you say I can join the tables using `JOIN table AS alias`, but my knowledge of MyBatis does not include a way to map those results to the mappers without duplicating them completely.

Comment: It is all in the fine Manual: `select
    <include refid="userColumns"><property name="alias" value="t1"/></include>,
    <include refid="userColumns"><property name="alias" value="t2"/></include>
  from some_table t1
    cross join some_table t2`

Comment: @joop Ah I did not know you could pass variables to sql statements. I'll look into it, thanks! Link to the manual for the lazy: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to join D to both tables B and C alias them in accordingly.

Let's say **bd** for table d joined to B and **cd**.

now if you want same resultmap of table **d** for both aliased table (bd and cd), you can do this:

```
select bd.did as bd_did, cd.did as cd_did
```

And if you have not come across `column_prefix` property of result maps this is how your resultmap will look

```
<collection type="D" resultMap="d" column_prefix="bd_" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually went down this road in the end, and it's up and running now!

Comment: Oh I was also kind of late. But if others find that useful!